# Check does value exits in export class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, include

I have some class like this

```
export interface ILanguage {
  shortName: string;
  shortNameLowercase: string;
  fullName: string;
}

export class Language {
  static readonly ENGLISH: ILanguage = { shortName: 'EN', shortNameLowercase: 'en', fullName: 'ENGLISH' };
  static readonly DUTCH: ILanguage = { shortName: 'NL', shortNameLowercase: 'nl', fullName: 'DUTCH' };
  static readonly FRENCH: ILanguage = { shortName: 'FR', shortNameLowercase: 'fr', fullName: 'FRENCH' };
}
```

And i have currentLanguage like this

```
currentLanguage = 'de';
```

Now i need to check does `currentLanguage` exist in class Language, i have tried

```
  if (Object.values(Language).includes(currentLanguage)) {
..}
```

But i didnt work well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Object.keys instead. `Object.keys(Language)` will give you `["ENGLISH", "DUTCH", "FRENCH"]`. For these you can lookup for a language with the right name.

```
Object.keys(Language).some(k => Language[k].shortNameLowercase == currentLanguage)
```